# Mysql - Set key of row from recurring field in a 3 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have a table with 2 fields, key and value in group of 3 rows. Example:

```
Key  value

Name   Apple
Id     1
Price  25
Name   Banana 
Id     2
Price  23
Name   Orange
Id     3
Price  27
```

How could i query to get results with 3 values in row with Id as key?

I want the output rows will be like:

```
id-> 1   Name -> Apple  Price ->  25
id-> 2   Name -> Banana Price ->  23
id-> 3   Name -> Orange Price ->  27
```

Tried with group by, but no luck. I know how tables should be, this is data from a old system and i wonder if there is a way to do this with Mysql. (I know how do this with php/ruby/python etc)

Comment: SQL tables represented *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as groups of three rows, unless another column specifies the ordering or have some sort of id to tie the rows together.

Comment: i agree with Gordon. you can't make sure that the id, name, price will store in order, unless you have another column to make it in order, otherwise all the answer won't return the desire result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I preface this with imo, it should ***not*** work.  And you obviously know this is a terrible database design.  You are missing a key field with this table.

However, this ***might*** work in some circumstances.  `Sql` in nature is *unordered* -- this means you need to have some field to establish the order.

You need a row number and a row grouping to get your results.  Generally you'd do this with ordering by a different field.  This solution attempts to do it without altering the ordering and uses `user-defined variables` with `conditional aggregation` to pivot the results.

```
select max(case when `rn` = 2 then `value` end) as `Id`,
       max(case when `rn` = 1 then `value` end) as `Name`,
       max(case when `rn` = 3 then `value` end) as `Price`
from (
  select *, 
      @rn:=if(@rn>2,1,@rn+1) rn,
      @row:=if(@rn=1,@row+1,@row) `row`
  from `yourmesseduptable` cross join (select @rn:=0, @row:=0) t
  ) t
group by `row`
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae81f/1)

*Again, there are lots of situations where this won't return the desired results.*